# Conditional Group By statement using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement, group-by, conditional-statements

I have what seems to be a fairly simple requirement, but looking around I'm not able to get a simple answer for this. I have looked on MSDN forums, Exper Exchange and nothing substantial was given to me.

I have the following LINQ code

```
Dim SummaryLog As IQueryable(Of clPartCountSummary)    
SummaryLog = From Inventory In db.tblPartCounts _
            Where Inventory.InventoryCountId = InventoryCountId _
            And Not Inventory.ActionId.HasValue _
            Group By PartNumber = Inventory.PartNumber _
            , Inventory.RevLevel, SAPLocation = Inventory.SAPLocation _
            Into AggregatedProdLog = Group, Qty = Sum(Inventory.Quantity) _
            Select New clPartCountSummary With 
                {.PartNumber = PartNumber, 
                 .RevLevel = RevLevel, 
                 .Qty = Qty, 
                 .SAPLocation = SAPLocation}
```

I want to be able to conditionally group by on `RevLevel` and `SAPLocation`.  I will always group by `PartNumber`, but the other two are optional. So if a variable `bRevLevel` is true then we group by `RevLevel` and if `bSAPLocation` is true then we group by `SAPLocation` as well.

Any help will be much appreciated, I'm at the stage where multiple `SummaryLog` definitions are starting to look appealing.

Thanks, Tomasz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this helps....

```
public class TblPartCount
{
    public int InventoryCountID { get; set; }
    public int? ActionID { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public int RevLevel { get; set; }
    public string SAPLocation { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

private static void ConditionalGroupBy()
    {
        bool pCheck = true;

        var lList = new List<TblPartCount>
                        {
                            new TblPartCount { InventoryCountID = 1, ActionID = 2, PartNumber = "123", RevLevel = 1, SAPLocation = "AAAA", Quantity = 100 },
                            new TblPartCount { InventoryCountID = 1, ActionID = 2, PartNumber = "123", RevLevel = 1, SAPLocation = "BBBB", Quantity = 200 }
                        };

        var lOutput = lList
                          .Where(pArg => pArg.InventoryCountID == 1)
                          .Where(pArg => pArg.ActionID != null)
                          .GroupBy(pArg => new
                          {
                              PartNumber = pArg.PartNumber,
                              RevLevel = pCheck ? pArg.RevLevel : 0,
                              SAPLocation = pCheck ? pArg.SAPLocation : String.Empty
                          })
                          .Select(pArg =>
                                    new
                                    {
                                        PartNumber = pArg.Key.PartNumber,
                                        RevLevel = pArg.Key.RevLevel,
                                        SAPLocation = pArg.Key.SAPLocation,
                                        Qtry = pArg.Sum(pArg1 => pArg1.Quantity)
                                    });

        foreach (var lItem in lOutput)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lItem);
        }
    }
```